# Отображение блока, когда он появился в поле видимости?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такой html:

```
<header>
</header>
<section class="welcome">
    <h1>на протяжении 30 лет занимается строительством домов по фахверк-технологии </h1>
</section>
```

Нужно, что бы как только в поле зрения появляется блок section у header менялся класс. Сейчас у меня такой код:

```
function scrollMe() {
    $(window).scroll(function () {

        //var refTarget = $('.navigation__list a');

        if ($(window).scrollTop() < '600') {
            $('header').addClass('header__wrap-scrolled');
        }
```

Но это не работает, так как расстояние постоянно меняется и появляется он то рано, то поздно. Есть решение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете узнать позицию `section` так:

```
$('section').offset().top
```

и сравнить с `$(window).scrollTop()`